# What pointing devices can be used with iPadOS 13?

Tags: bluetooth, ipados

For reasons that are beyond incomprehensible to me, Apple is not supporting Apple pointing devices for use with iPadOS 13.  Nor are they providing a list of supported devices.  I spent a great deal of time trying to get my trackpad to work before discovering the fine print that Apple won't even support its own hardware.

Googling 'bluetooth pointing devices compatible with ipad' does not yield any useful results.

How can I know what to buy without wasting immense time and money through trial and error?

Update: I am *not* asking how to enable the feature.  That is readily available in the search results.

Answer (score 1):

I have used multiple Logitech Bluetooth mice and they have all seemed to work just fine (my daily driver is the MX Vertical).

I do believe any generic bluetooth mouse works just fine (and by generic i mean it at least has a scroll wheel, 2 buttons and a laser at the bottom)

Answer (score 0):

Although there have been reports of "bluetooth mouse support" in iPadOS 13, it's not a feature meant for general end-user or everyday use. It's not officially stated, but apparent that Apple doesn't want everyone to be using a mouse with their iPad running iPadOS 13, else it would have been advertised in events and website.

The mouse support is an accessibility feature and can be enabled from within the Accessibility section of the Settings app.

On your iPad (running iPadOS 13 or later), go to Settings app → Accessibility → Touch → and enable **AssistiveTouch**. Now, under Pointing Devices tap on **Bluetooth Devices...** to pair your Bluetooth mouse. (The mouse should be in pairing mode).

There is no official list of supported devices published by Apple. You will need to check yourself if your device works this way or not.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question, and mainly just repeats information already included in the question (there's no official list, I can waste my time with trial and error...)